# Using MD5/SHA1 to compare XML instances

Tags: xml, hash, comparison, md5

I was recently trying to figure out the fastest way to compare two large XML documents and a co-worker recommended hashing them and then just comparing the hash strings.

At first this seemed like an obvious/brilliant idea! But then something instinctively told me that it might be "too good to be true".

Just like serializing POJOs for comparison/cloning is widely regarded as "bad practice", is the same true for this technqiue? Why or why not? Caveats/pitfalls, etc.?

Comment: at the risk of sounding obtuse, it really depends on why you want to make a comparison. eg: for a backup system where you need to record changes, then taking a hash is ok. for just knowing if two files are the same or different, a byte for byte comparison can be very fast (oops! first byte is different. stop right here) whereas something like [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm) is O(n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start by saying that XML comparison is tricky. It's tricky because, as you very well put it in the title of your question, you are comparing XML instances.

XMLs are not just content (text files, binary files etc) that you can compare to see if something differs; XML has meaning, and different XML instances can have the same meaning.

For example, consider this XML sample:

```
<sample a="foo" b="bar" />
```

Is that different than this?

```
<sample b='bar' a='foo' />
```

or this:

```
<sample 
a="foo" 
b="bar" />
```

or even this?:

```
<sample a="foo" b="bar"></sample>
```

The answer is that the samples are all equal. But if you hash each one you will get different hashes each time.

If you want to hash XML instances and use the hash for comparison, you first must get them into [a canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML). If the XMLs don't change often, you can store the hash along side the XML and then just compare hashes. You compute the message digest only when something changes. This can be very fast.

One other solution would also be to have [an XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) transformation and use the two XML instances as input. You then output something simpler (maybe a flat file with all the element and attribute names and values) which is simpler to compare.

There are [lots of ways to compare XML](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compare%20XML%20documents) files and as @violet313 mentioned in the comment, it really depends on why you want to make a comparison and what exactly you want to compare.

Comment: I appreciate the great answer! In hindsight I should have mentioned in my post that the XML instances are generated by XStream, so the same POJOs will be converted to the same XML, and *should* unless I'm missing anything map to the same hashed values. So I don't think this is an issue for us - but point very well made!

Answer (score 1):

Computing the hashes requires reading the entire files anyway, and spend CPU cycle computing it, so why not do byte to byte comparison if you are not worried about the files being different yet semantically identical?

Also both the hash you cited have issues (MD5 more so) and should not be used if there is any risk that someone could have any incentive to create documents having the same hash yet being different (this is readily doable with MD5 which is completely broken from a cryptographic point of view, and possibly not far away with SHA1).

Basically what you propose (hashing then compare the hashes) is likely slower than plain compare (unless you read from a really seek averse media) and have issues of its own. That and in the context of XML documents you likely want a more high level approach as Bogdan pretty much nails it up.